# Predicting peaks in time series using multistep LSTM

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I'm working on a problem trying to predict the peak value in a thunderstorm wind speed record. I have many wind records from different locations across the US (each record should be around 120 points). My question is how to manipulate the `LSTM` architecture to better handle those peaks.

Example of the used TS record:

[image: Example of the used TS record]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY4TD.png)

My basic intuition is to give more attention to the peak values by modifying the loss function or using attention, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.